# Android. Is it possible get cached bitmap with glide?

Tags: android, android-glide, android-bitmap, android-image, coil

Is it possible to get cached bitmap by key with `glide` like in `coil` ?
For example my code with coil:

```
val bitmap =  imageLoader.memoryCache?.get(cacheKey) as? Bitmap?
```

And my request to show page:

```
 val request = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
                                .size(width, height)
                                .memoryCacheKey(cacheKey)
                                .data(bitmap)
                                .build()
```

So if my bitmap != null I'm not render pdf page.

Now I want to do something similar with `glide`. But I didn't find a suitable way. Please let me know if this is possible with glide ?